# Excel 2010 Select Data making dynamic to static range

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I load this into a charts Select Data field ='Metrics Test 2.xlsx'!ROFPS_Range and the chart works fine.  If I change the range I am working with the formula is changed to ='UW ATO'!$B$10:$B$15 and the Series name is lost.  Now the chart range is static and I need it dynamic  How can I keep the original formula?

Comment: Welcome to superuser! Could you please try to explain what are you working on? Try to make a small sample showing what do you have in the spreadsheet and what would you like to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

i have the same issue. I just used VBA to reset the chart's data source. It's not the most flexible code ever, but it solves my problem. Just to be clear, my data and chart sit in a tab called outputchart. that data source is called rngChartData, and this is a dynamic range using the usual OFFSET construction

```
Sub UpdateChart()
    Sheets("outputchart").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("rngchartdata")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem a few weeks back. Excel doesn't seem to remember dynamic names for charts/graphs data ranges. The only workaround I found was to create a pivot chart.

1. Create a pivot table based on data in your table range `'UW ATO'!$B$10:$B$15` (or however long you want it to be) and be sure to include the adjacent columns that contain axis labels.
2. Put your axis labels in the rows field, and your values in the value field of the pivot table.
3. Put a filter on your row labels to exclude empty labels (Contains `?` worked for me but different data types might require a different solution).
4. Add a pivot chart based on your pivot table.

Downside is that this pivot chart needs to be refreshed manually. I ended up adding a VBA button to do this based on the macro recorder:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UW ATO").PivotTables("YOUR PIVOT TABLE NAME").PivotCache.Refresh
```

But really, I'm hoping someone has a better solution.